UUID in request header of HTTP POST
I am trying generate a unique identifier (thread safe) and send it as part of request header in HTTP POST call of a heavily loaded REST service.
Read https://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid for initial understanding, now as the service will be called heavily, trying to ensure unique customized UUID (with hex characters + extra text) is generated for every call and passed in header (REST client uses RestTemplate of Spring).
Appreciate any suggestions/thoughts?

The only means for you to guarantee uniqueness is to expose an endpoint that the client calls to get the UUID before calling your endpoint that consumes it.

thanks for comment. Please note that here the UUID needs to be generated at our / client side to be passed to service.

The chance of a UUID colliding is extremely unlikely, but it is possible. Just know that if you are relying on the client alone to create these, there's a chance that you will get a duplicate. It honestly doesn't make a lot of sense for the client to arbitrarily create some unique value to send with the request.
